# How to correctly embed a Perl interpreter in a C++ application on Windows

Tags: c++, perl, visual-studio

I have a Perl script of about 15,000 lines that I want to execute with a `PerlInterpreter` from a Windows executable compiled with C++.

I tried, following [these directions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlinterp.html)

I downloaded Perl 5.18 source and included the core (install) directory, for `perl.h`, and `EXTERN.h`, as well as `core/win32` and `core/win32/include`

Then I tried compiling the simple C++ project in Visual Studio 2013

```
#include <EXTERN.h>               /* from the Perl distribution     */
#include <perl.h>                 /* from the Perl distribution     */

static PerlInterpreter *my_perl;  /***    The Perl interpreter    ***/

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
  PERL_SYS_INIT3(&argc,&argv,&env);
  my_perl = perl_alloc();
  perl_construct(my_perl);
  PL_exit_flags |= PERL_EXIT_DESTRUCT_END;
  perl_parse(my_perl, NULL, argc, argv, (char **)NULL);
  perl_run(my_perl);
  perl_destruct(my_perl);
  perl_free(my_perl);
  PERL_SYS_TERM();
}
```

The project did not compile, giving hundreds of errors, but most prevalent error was

```
missing config.h file included by perl.h
```

So I added a `#define PERL_MICRO` statement to `perl.h`

This reduced the number of errors to 20

However all of the errors originate from Windows SDK files `string.h` and `guidedef.h`
so I am clueless as to what is the origin of these errors

Can anyone provide me with any information on how to create and build a C++ interpreter for Perl scripts?

---

The remaining errors are

```
Error   10  error C3861: 'my_memcmp': identifier not found  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\shared\guiddef.h    161 1   

Error   3   error C2733: 'memmove_s' : second C linkage of overloaded function not allowed  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\string.h 136 1   

Error   4   error C2733: 'memmove' : second C linkage of overloaded function not allowed    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\string.h 139 1   

Error   2   error C2733: 'memcpy_s' : second C linkage of overloaded function not allowed   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\string.h 57  1   

Error   1   error C2733: 'memcpy' : second C linkage of overloaded function not allowed c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\string.h 55  1   

Error   8   error C2732: linkage specification contradicts earlier specification for 'strstr'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\string.h 228 1   

Error   7   error C2732: linkage specification contradicts earlier specification for 'strrchr'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\string.h 226 1   

Error   6   error C2732: linkage specification contradicts earlier specification for 'strpbrk'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\string.h 224 1   

Error   5   error C2732: linkage specification contradicts earlier specification for 'strchr'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\string.h 222 1   

Error   9   error C2732: linkage specification contradicts earlier specification for 'memchr'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\string.h 233 1
```

Comment: You seem to be changing things at random in an attempt to get rid of the error messages; that isn't a good way to work. Those messages aren't a problem in themselves but they are alerting you to an issue that you need to solve. I am not sure what the solution to your problem is, but hacking Perl release files isn't part of it. If you want `PERL_MICRO` defined for a build then you need to modify your Visual Studio project to define it. The header files form the definition of the interface to the Perl compiler/interpreter and you can't just change them at a whim.

Answer (score 5):

I'll describe some things I know on the subject. I hope this will help.

First you should specify which Perl you're using on Windows.
There are at least 2 I know of on Windows:

- [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/)
- [Activestate Perl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl)

Second, what you're trying to achieve is `Embedding a Perl interpreter in a C/C++ application`. I mention this so you can refer to it when you search for documentation about it.

The [perlembed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html) documentation provides general information about this.

If you want to do this on Windows with ActivePerl you can have a look at the [Embedding Perl Under WIN32](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/lib/pods/perlembed.html#embedding_perl_under_win32).

For Strawberry Perl, [someone on Perlmonks has a working example](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1074546) of embedding Perl on Windows here.

At the same time, notice that it may be useful to follow the [perlwin32](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlwin32.html) perl documentation page in order to set up the MSVC compiler with the appropriate paths.

Finally, there's also a book on the topic called [Extending and Embedding Perl](http://www.manning.com/jenness/) which you may want to look at for some details on the topic. In this book, chapter 8 discusses embedding Perl in C in general, and chapter 9 deals with an embedding case study.

**UPDATE**:

Reading through [`ExtUtils::MakeMaker`](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker) documentation I've found this part which looked interesting:

`If you are running experiments with embedding perl as a library into other applications, you might find MakeMaker is not sufficient. You'd better have a look at ExtUtils::Embed which is a collection of utilities for embedding.`

And in particular [ExtUtils::Embed](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils%3a%3aEmbed) is concerned with `Utilities for embedding Perl in C/C++ applications`.

I haven't tried it myself but I'm thinking it could help. I'll come back with more details once I get some time to look into this.

**UPDATE**:

A list of applications that feature an embedded Perl interpretor:

- [Pidgin](https://pidgin.im/) - in particular offers you the possibility to write plugins that run via its embedded Perl interpretor. This is an interesting example as it's also known to work under Windows. Of interest here, seems to be [libpurple/plugins/perl](https://hg.pidgin.im/pidgin/main/file/27580a47ae28/libpurple/plugins/perl) and in particular the [Makefile.mingw](https://hg.pidgin.im/pidgin/main/file/27580a47ae28/libpurple/plugins/perl/Makefile.mingw) which should contain information on how to build on Windows
- [Irssi](http://www.irssi.org/) - here `ExtUtils::Embed` is used inside `configure.in` ( see `git clone git://git.irssi.org/irssi` for details, or [svn.irssi.org](http://svn.irssi.org/) )
- [Vim](http://www.vim.org/)   - (Also uses `ExtUtils::Embed` in its `configure.in`. For more details `hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim`. Vim also [allows](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_perl.html) [scripting via Perl](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_embedded_Perl_interpreter).)
- [Icinga](http://icinga.org/) - Icinga [allows scripting in Perl](http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/epnplugins.html)
- [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) - A relevant article about Nagios in this context can be [found here](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/embeddedperl.html) .
- [collectd](http://collectd.org/documentation.shtml) - [Makefile.am](http://git.verplant.org/?p=collectd.git;a=blob;f=src/Makefile.am;h=a9d858232a9ec547f42e52d335b1d3e5ff2da5eb;hb=master) and [perl.c](http://git.verplant.org/?p=collectd.git;a=blob;f=src/perl.c;h=78e508ae4d1f1bb7c0b9ae5c9ca340b9685e79e6;hb=master)

Comment: Thank you, I will search for a solution within these documents. I have both Strawberry Perl and Activestate Perl installed. As for the sources, I am not sure which I downloaded, since the website http://www.perl.org/get.html (sources section) does not specify which version it is. For now I have decided to abandon perl and re-write the application in C, since that is the eventual goal of my application.